# Ionic - ANDROID_HOME not found in linux/ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, ionic-framework, environment-variables

I am very new in ionic.
I have a problem that build android platform from ionic.

I have set up the environment variable for ANDROID_HOME in .bashrc file.

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/lukyuxuan/Desktop/android-sdk-linux
export ANDROID_HOME
export ANDROID_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_TOOLS:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS
```

In the terminal:

I try to print out the ANDROID_HOME (echo "$ANDROID_HOME"), it is work return the path

But when I try to build the android platform like this:

```
$ sudo ionic build android
```

There's still occur this error. I also many answer for google, but no any one work for my situation.

Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `sudo` will drop most unknown env variables.

I don't see why `sudo` is necessary here though.